# Enabling GD & MySQL in PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, amazon-ec2, gd

I've Yumed the following onto my server:

httpd php mysql mysql-server php-mysql php-gd

They all installed fine.

Should GD and MySQL be available in PHP after installing those packages, even if phpinfo() doesn't have GD or MySQL listed anywhere except for '--without-mysql', etc in the configure parameters?

Or do I have to enable the modules manually somewhere?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after installing?

Comment: If phpinfo() doesn't list them then they are not available. (My phpinfo() outputs show gd, mysql, mysqli (and mysql under PDO)). Typically though, the packages you listed (and their dependencies) are sufficient. Off-hand suggestions are to ensure you are looking at the right install of PHP (check the php.ini file) and to restart httpd/mysqld. (Check /etc/php.d - there should be ini files that have 'extension=mysql.so' and 'extension=gd.so' - but they are normally created automatically.

Comment: *sigh* Of course a restart would fix it. I thought I did that, but apparently not. Thanks, and if you post it as an answer I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini you have to enable extension=php_gd2.dll, or where ever gd is installed too, it will typically be in c:\php\extensions

or in linux

## extension=php_gd2.dll

To:

extension=php_gd2.dll

You may also have to correct the extension directory setting from:

extension_dir = "./"

Or:

extension_dir = "./extensions"

I hope that helps